# Is there a way to change the color of your website when refreshing it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have made a website with one specific theme, is there a way to change the color of the background/text of the website when you refresh it? here is some code which can only change the background. How to make it so it will pick a theme with the text and background

Comment: You can create a preset themes that is used to style the page and randomize the theme based on timestamp or a random number.

Comment: Share some code. What you mean by *"theme"* might not be what we think of *theming* a website. To answer your question: **just change a theme class** to the `body` element using JS and classList.toggle/remove/add. CSS should do the rest. `.theme-matrix h1 { /*heading styles for Matrix theme*/ };` do you get the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want change color of background or text, use DOM to access this style and edit:

```
var bgcolorArr = new Array("silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3", "red", "green", "blue")
document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorArr.length)]
```

Update!!
Use Array literals is shorter new Array():

```
var bgcolorArr = ["silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3", "red", "green", "blue"]
```

Comment: Why don't you use `[]` instead of `new Array()`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, you right, use [] is soft than new Array(), i will edited my post.